# How to secure API to be consumed by my webapp and by individual users?

Tags: rest, authentication, fastapi, sveltekit, api-key

I am designing a web app and am having trouble finding best practices for what I am trying to achieve. For context, I am building an app that stores text data for users, its essentially a more complex "to-do" app.

I am using SvelteKit to build the frontend and some of the backend, along with Supabase for authentication and database. I would like to build the actual logic of the backend using FastAPI, and use the SvelteKit server routes as a proxy to the FastAPI routes. This much I understand I can do.

One feature I would like to implement is issuing API keys to users such that they can access their data programmatically. I understand how I can issue keys and then authenticate them on the backend.

However, I am confused how I can authenticate the SvelteKit app to the API. My only idea is that I issue an API key for the SvelteKit app that has full database access and use that in the SvelteKit server routes. I know that the key will be hidden from the client, since server routes are executed server side only. And I can be sure that a user is authenticated on the server side via Supabase.

But, issuing a API key like this seems risky to me, and I'm curious if there is a better way to go about this.